# What is wrong with my .htaccess redirect code?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I thought this would be easy. I am simply trying to redirect one page (index.html) to another page (index.php) by adding to the .htaccess file, and whatever I do, the original file (index.html) is still being displayed. .htaccess page already has code to cover SSL. The host is NamesCo.

Code I have now:

```
# BEGIN SSL Redirect
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [R=301,L] 
# END SSL Redirect
```

code I have also tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.html/ /index.php/
Redirect 301 /index.html / index.php/
Redirect 301 "index.html" "index.php"
```

I8 am clearly doing something wrong, but cannot see what it is, so at the moment I am reduced to using http refresh for my redirects, but I hate doing that.

Can anyone help?

Comment: That `RewriteRule` should work, although the implementation certainly could be enhanced. So the question is: why does it _not_ work? Could it be that you are looking at a cached response, cached on the client side? Did you _really_ make a "deep reload" or use a new anonymous browser instance? What is the exact response you see in your browsers networking console?

Comment: @arkascha All that happened was the original page was displayed, so there was no response. Yes, I cleared the cache several times and used the incognito view function.

Comment: Sorry, but that statement is a contradiction in itself... If "the original page was displayed" then there must have been some response, exactly that page. Where else should it come from? Thin air? The question is just whether the response came from the server as a response to an actually sent request, or where the response comes from the client side cache without the request being sent at all. But you simply cannot see a page without any response!

Comment: @arkashca. Yes of course you are correct. What I meant was that there was no response to the .htaccess file, despite clearing the cache. The problem is now solved. Thanks for taking the time to respond :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have fixed it after some more experimentation. I first removed the existing SSL rewrite code and used the canonical tag for that instead. Then the .htaccess file reads:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index.html /index.php
Redirect 301 /aboutUs/about_us.htm /aboutUs/about_us.php
Redirect 301 /aboutUs/bookings.htm /aboutUs/bookings.php
Redirect 301 /aboutUs/maps.htm /aboutUs/maps.php
Redirect 301 /east_wing/bedroom.html /east_wing/bedroom.php
Redirect 301 /east_wing/lounge.html /east_wing/lounge.php
Redirect 301 /east_wing/ew_index.htm /east_wing/ew_index.php
Redirect 301 /east_wing/guestbook.html /east_wing/guestbook.php
Redirect 301 /fife/vivitor_attractions.htm /east_wing/visitor_attractions.php
</IfModule>
```

Many thanks

Tog :-)